# Batch - How to find folder, if path is unknown

Tags: windows, batch-file

So, my Coworker asked me to create batch for him, that will move File(In my case, ZIP) from Network folder, to another Network folder. Coworker will be using this batch script from time to time on his Thumb flash drive.

Any way, I've got my batch script to do this:

1. Go to \folder1\archive.
2. `move "\\folder1\archive\file.zip" "\\###.###.#.#\Newfolder\Archive"`

Now, I have problem. When my coworker will use this script on other computers, path to zip file will not work. That means, that I need to somehow find the path.

This is how path will change on other computers:

move "\"another folder"\archive\file.zip" "\###.###.#.#\Newfolder\Archive"

So my question is, how do I find path to "Another folder" ?

Comment: `move` can't move a file to another disk (because it doesn't touch the file itself, but only changes the file allocation table). Use `copy` or `xcopy` and `del` instead.

Comment: Could you please take a look at these screens? Maybe I am stupid or smth. but I really can't understand why exactly I can't use move? It looks fine to me.

[link](https://postimg.org/gallery/111p3kuqu/96410afa/)

Comment: uhm - sorry, I confused `move` with `ren`. You are right, you can use `move` here.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly. UNC File paths are `\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext` so your move won't work. Other file paths are `Drive:\folder\file.ext` and relative paths `\subfolderofcurrentfolder\file.ext`.

```
Dir c:\filename.ext /s
```

searches for a file. To get answer

```
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir c:\file.ext /a /s /b') Do echo %%A
```

Comment: Hey, I created new batch file and tested path that I mentioned. Everything worked (By Newfolder I meant sharename), but told me, that I don't have access. I guess script needs to be runned as admin. However this is not why I wanted to write this comment. I wanted to ask you, could you please explain code you added below? How do I add it to code, so that It searches for right sharename? (I am preety new at batch scripting).

Comment: Ok, so I found out how this command works, but important question here is, How do I parse results into all cd, move, etc. commands?

Comment: Relative paths starting with a single backslash are relative to __root of current drive__ and __NOT__ relative to __current directory__. Try it out in a command prompt window with `cd /D "%windir%\temp"` and run next `cd \Windows` or `cd "\program files"` and you will be one level up in directory tree in Windows directory or in program files directory on same drive. A relative path for a file or folder in current directory or one of its subdirectories starts either with file/folder name or with ``.\`` and ``..\`` references the parent directory of current directory.